# How to create a script that checks if certain programs are installed before installing the main program

Tags: bash, shell, bin

I have an school assingment to write a script for LAMP and I want to have a command line which checks if mysql and apache are installed before php gets installed and if they are not installed dont run the php install
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxwrl.jpg

Comment: Please add steps on what you have tried.

Comment: Sounds like you want autoconf

Comment: I added a picture of my code i used apt-cache policy to check if its installed

Answer (score 0):

You can search for binaries with `whereis`, but you'll have to parse the string yourself because you can't relay on the exit code (always 0).

```
$ PACKAGE=apache2
$ whereis -b ${PACKAGE} | wc -l 
apache2: /usr/sbin/apache2 /usr/lib/apache2 /etc/apache2 /usr/share/apache2
$ test `whereis -b ${PACKAGE} | wc -c` -gt $((${#PACKAGE}+2))
$ echo $?
0

$ PACKAGE=notinstalledpackage
$ test `whereis -b ${PACKAGE} | wc -c` -gt $((${#PACKAGE}+2))
$ echo $?
1
```